# Sensor to detect the closeness of an Object to the Mobile

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android: turn off screen when close to face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018716/android-turn-off-screen-when-close-to-face)

how can i detect that my face is close to the mobile , for example :-
when i have answered to incoming call , the screen of the mobile turned-off , and when i move the device away , the screen is turned on again ,,how can we code this

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is called proximity sensor.