# I want my program to do what android does when on call and close to face.

Tags: java, android

I know that this is similiat to this question
[android: turn off screen when close to face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018716/android-turn-off-screen-when-close-to-face)
and many others. But I could't find any working solution.

So I have a program that plays audio. I listen to proximity sensor:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(event.values[0] == 0.0){
        //phone close to face
        playAudio();
    }else{
        //phone away
        stopAudio();
    }
```

I have used this code to disable creen when close to face:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.screenBrightness = 0;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

But I don't know how to get it back :)
I tried:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.screenBrightness = 1f; //tried all (1, 100, -1, 0)
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

And some suggested:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

But nothing works. The audio is stopped when I move phone away from face. So activity is not paused.

Answer (score 0):

Save the previous screen brightness value in a variable and than restore it using
setAttributes

For example:

```
// Before changing brightness to 0
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
float oldScreenBrightness = params.screenBrightness; // Save the brightness param
//... Your code

// When u want to restore the brightness
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.screenBrightness = oldScreenBrightness;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

Comment: It's not working. That work's only if when I set screen brightness (when close to face) to something bigger..like 0.1f (only dim's the display). If I set screen brightness to 0..your code it's not working.