# [Help]Turn off the screen when touching the proximity sensor in Android

Tags: android, sensors, proximity

I want the screen will be turned off permanently but unlock when touching the proximity sensor and when untouching it, the screen will return to normal brightness (like in normal calls).
Now, I am using the way which has just blurred the screen without turning it off permanently.

```
Window mywindow = getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = mywindow.getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = 0.01f;
mywindow.setAttributes(lp);
```

Hope for your help

Comment: You want to turn off the screen or just lower the brightness?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android: turn off screen when close to face](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018716/android-turn-off-screen-when-close-to-face)

Comment: @stack_ved: I want to turn off the screen :D
@ NikolaDespotoski: thanks u. Let me try looking for

Comment: Tried using this: ((PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).goToSleep(2000); ??

Answer (score 0):

Your choice will lower the brightness and hence it is blurred. If u want to put the screen off, you have to make your app a device administrator and take the required permissions in manifest.

Comment: Thanks u for answer.

Can u speak/ describe more specifically?